# How to combine several rasters into one attribute table with no value changes in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, attribute-table, excel

I have a set of 1000 rasters that I need to copy into excel to process some data. I want to know if there is a way to combine these rasters so I have one attribute table that keeps the properties of each individual rasters. therefore when I copy the attribute table into excel I can difference the data from each raster. The rasters don't overlap with each other.

Comment: Ideally, I would recommend Combine tool, but it has limit of 20 rasters. If you want spatial and tabular information then I would look at Mosaic to New Raster tool or Cell Statistics.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the Spatial Analyst extension, you could try the *Sample* tool. Description at this [link](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/sample.htm)